# Stash : Can I pass a stash_list into a stash:embed file?

Tags: stash

I'm trying to pass in a stash list into my embed file. It does seem to pass in the values but outputting the result does not seem to work.

Master Template:

```
    {exp:stash:set_list name="hours_list" parse_tags="yes"}
    {tunnel_hours}
        {stash:item_day}{day}{/stash:item_day}
        {stash:item_hours}{hours}{/stash:item_hours}
    {/tunnel_hours}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
{stash:embed:inc:sidebar-services-tunnels stash:hours="{stash:hours_list}"}
```

Embed Template:

{stash:hours_list} creates the following

```
item_day|=|Monday|&|item_hours|=|9-6|+|item_day|=|Tuesday|&|item_hours|=|9-6|+|item_day|=|Wednesday|&|item_hours|=|9-6|+|item_day|=|Thursday|&|item_hours|=|9-6|+|item_day|=|Friday|&|item_hours|=|9-6|+|item_day|=|Saturday|&|item_hours|=|10-8|+|item_day|=|Sunday|&|item_hours|=|10-8
```

This displays nothing:

```
        {exp:stash:get_list name="{stash:hours_list}"}
        <h1>{item_day}</h1>
        {item_hours}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the list name just be hours_list in the get_list?  Or are you deliberately using a stash variable for the list name?

That is, if you're using that set_list above, then

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="{stash:hours_list}"}
```

Should be

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="hours_list"}
```

...unless you're trying to actually name your list as the contents of {stash:hours_list}